# Theme dependent colors for Windows Phone 8

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, themes

I've almost scratch to the center of my brain (if any) on this one.

I'm developing a simple Windows Phone 8 application and I'm trying to figure out how I can define colors depending on what theme the user selected.

For example,
if theme = light:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DialogBackground" Color="#FFEEDD" />
```

if theme = dark:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DialogBackground" Color="#001122" />
```

The internet is full of information on this topic, but `ResourceDictionary.ThemeResources` is only available for Windows Phone 8.1.

Every page is visited explains about system wide colors and brushes, but never how to define your own in your application.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**ADDED INFO**

I'm trying to find out if there's a built-in way to achieve this behavior without having to iterate all my colors inside an if-clause.

I know how to use static colordefinitions, I was just wondering how I could define my own colors in a way that my application knows what color to use depending on the selected theme

Answer (score 0):

There are colors defined, that always apply to the current theme. 
An example:

`Color="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"`

will change dependent on the theme. There are about a couple of dozen of colors defined in the `StaticResource` that are theme dependent. You can read more about themes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402557(v=vs.105).aspx
This also applies to fonts.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear in my question about this. I know how to use static colordefinitions, I was just wondering how I could define my own colors in a way that my application knows what color to use depending on the selected theme

Comment: Well there is probably no 'clean' way to achieve that.